# Adding a UICollectionViewController inside another UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am writing a project where I need to display a list of players (avatars) in a horizontal collection view controller / list, let's call this a HUD.

I want this HUD to be common, that is to say: I know this one component will repeat many times throughout the app.

I do not want to write the Collection View code over and over again.

I want to add the collection view to an existing view controller which already has a collection view.

Almost like an in-line Master-detail display where the master does not change from page to page.

Is there a way in Swift where I can instantiate the HUD collection View and append it to whatever View Controller I am in.

I have included a picture.

[image: Inline master detail idea]

Thus my query is this:

How do I include a collection view controller inside another View controller that already has a UICollectionViewController?

How do I share this HUD component across multiple screens in the app?

Many thanks

Comment: Embed Collection Controller or Collection View?

Comment: Create collectionview cell In XIB for your HUD so you can use it anywhere you want, and for multiple collectionView in one ViewController  yes you can use it. you just need to write down collectonview datasource and delegate methods and in  that method you need to identify your collectionviews.

Comment: The HUD currently is a UICollectionViewController.   The pages that is holding the HUD is a standard UIViewController; some pages have a UICollectionView inside them.  So its multiple UICollectionViews on the same view controller.

Comment: @Prince is it not possible to have a standalone UICollectionViewController that is pulled into whatever page I want, regardless of whether its a UIView, etc and let the standalone UICollectionViewController handle all the delegate/data source stuff.     I understand that you can make the XIB standalone, and re-usable

Comment: @cardigan i haven't tried that UIcollectionviewController standalone, and i am not sure that we can pulled it to anywhere but if you go through XIB approach it might be fulfil your need.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a go.

Comment: I've found that you can use a `Container View` in the storyboard which defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a container view to solve my issue.  This issue is now closed.